# Nginx can't connect to website from specific devices

Tags: ssl, nginx

There is a weird issue I am having with my Nginx server. I am hosting static files using ssl with certificates from [1&1](https://www.ionos.co.uk/security/ssl-certificate). A friend from the UK and a friend from Germany have reported that they can not access my website while multiple friends from Germany and the UK can access the website without any issues. Non of the people who have tested have ever accessed the website before to make sure the test results aren't skewed with by browser history. When typing the url Nginx sends them to url/defaultpage which is not one of my routes.

I hosted the exact same website on a different machine running nginx 1.14.0 (instead of 1.16.1) which solved the issue for one of my testers. This seems very arbitrary, has anyone ever had this issue?

My config file

```
server {
  listen 0.0.0.0:443;
  root /home/ubuntu/vue-project/dist/;
  ssl on;
  ssl_certificate /home/ubuntu/vue-project/certs/bundle.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key /home/ubuntu/vue-project/certs/key.key;
  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
  }
}
```

A redirect script I am using to send all http requests to my https port

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;

    server_name _;

    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

Comment: It is unclear what you mean with "can not access". Are there any specific error messages in the browser? Also, given that you have an IPv4-only configuration: are you sure that the domain name does not resolve to both IPv4 and IPv6 so that you would also need to handle IPv6?

Comment: The Domain Name is linked to a specific IP address which I was given by my hosting Service as far as Im aware it only resolves to IPv4. By &quot;can not access&quot; I mean their Browser literaly tells them the website doesn&#39;t exist which makes sense since the Browser also redirected my test User from URL/ to URL/defaultpage which is indeed not a Website. This redirect seems to be the issue or is maybe a Symptom of the issue since I can not explain why nginx defaults to URL/defaultpage for some of my test users.

Comment: Could you please include the __exact__ and __full__ error message the users get and not your wording of what you understand they get? Also, have you checked that the get the same IP address for the domain, i.e. the same IPv4 you have and no IPv6 (*"as far as I'm aware"* is not sufficient, please check that your assumption is actually true).

Comment: Also make sure that these users actually use the exact same URL. `www.example.com` and `example.com` might show different behavior. `https://...` and `http://...` might show different behavior too.